# How to solve Java compareTo error cant find symbol

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting

Im a Java noob but still trying to learn by reverse engineering codes. I read similar questions but still not able to figure out.

Ive defined a quadruplet array pair as :-

The content of pairList array is (1:2:3:**6**), (3:4:1:**1**), (1:2:3:**3**)

I want to ascending sort the pairList based on the fourth element, so the output should be  (3:4:1:**1**), (1:2:3:**3**), (1:2:3:**6**)

```
public class Pair<L,C, R, S> {
        private L l;
        private R r;
        private C c;
        private S s;
        public Pair(L l, R r, C c, S s){

            this.l = l;
            this.r = r;
            this.c = c;
            this.s = s;
        }
        public L getL(){ return l; }
        public R getR(){ return r; }
        public C getC(){ return c; }
        public S getS(){ return s; }

        public void setL(L l){ this.l = l; }
        public void setR(R r){ this.r = r; }
        public void setC(C c){ this.c = c; }
        public void setS(S s){ this.s = s; }


    }

 List<Pair<String,Integer,Integer, Integer>> pairList = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Integer,Integer, Integer>>();
 // Code for array population

 Arrays.sort(pairList, new Comparator<Pair>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair p1, Pair p2) {
            return p1.getL().compareTo(p2.getL());
        }
    });
```

But Im getting this error :-

```
 error: cannot find symbol
                return p1.getL().compareTo(p2.getL());
                                ^
  symbol:   method compareTo(Object)
  location: class Object
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are using `Pair` as a raw type in your comparator, meaning you lose all information of what those pairs contain. The solution is to not use raw types and instead the correct generic parameters so that java knows what kind of objects your Pair contains. See: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: I did this but even this isnt working -->   public class Pair  implements Comparable Pair <L,C, R, S>      . Sorry but  I cant comprehend all the information in link you shared at this stage of learning. Can you please help me with my code Sir.

Comment: Try to use ``public class Pair<L extends Comparable<L>, C, R, S>`` and ``Collections.sort`` instead of ``Arrays.sort`` (or ``Comparator<Pair<String, Integer, Integer, Integer>> comparator = Comparator.comparing( Pair::getL ); pairList.sort( comparator );``).

Comment: @AnkitaJain Another error is you are trying to use `Arrays.sort` to sort an ArrayList. You can only sort arrays with that method not lists. Just use the lists sort method and as already said make sure you use the same generic type arguments for you pair everywhere: `pairList.sort(new Comparator<Pair<String,Integer,Integer, Integer>>() { public int compare(Pair<String,Integer,Integer, Integer> p1, Pair<String,Integer,Integer, Integer> p2) { //code here } }`

Comment: @MichaelCkr :-) Thanks Michael exactly what I was looking for.  public class Pair<L , C, R, S extends Comparable> worked for me

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Ok sir , Ill try this also